# Is there framework like Junit for Javascript to test object oriented javascript in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, unit-testing, testing

Are there any best pratices for testing object oriented javascript in Node.js?

Like for example if I had the following Cat.js class:

```
function Cat(age, name) {
    this.name = name || null;
    this.age = age || null;
}

Cat.prototype.getAge = function() {
    return this.age;
}

Cat.prototype.setAge = function(age) {
    this.age = age;
}

Cat.prototype.getName = function(name) {
    return this.name;
}

Cat.prototype.setName = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Cat.prototype.equals = function(otherCat) {
    return otherCat.getName() === this.getName()
        && otherCat.getAge() === this.getAge();
}

Cat.prototype.fill = function(newFields) {
    for (var field in newFields) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(field) && newFields.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
            if (this[field] !== 'undefined') {
                this[field] = newFields[field];
            }
        }
    }
};

module.exports = Cat;
```

and I wanted to write test classes that look something like the following like Java's junit tests:

```
var cat1;

setUp() {
    cat1 = new Cat(10, 'Tom');
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up this one's probably going to be flagged for closure as it's too broad (and is asking for external resource recommendations). Try refining it if you can.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#JavaScript  There are a number.

Comment: I wrote a small JS library called [Tidbits](https://github.com/najamelan/TidBits_Javascript) which both has an Object Oriented framework and a Unit testing framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are a number of them.  Answering which is the most popular and/or best is not possible.  But two common libraries are  Jasmine and Mocha

http://jasmine.github.io/

http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/

Comment: There is also JsUnit

Comment: Nowadays I would also add Jest to the list )

Comment: Jest is also there